# Критерии научного знания и достоверности ответов

Tags: обсуждение

Друзья-гуманитарии, объясните, пожалуйста, технарю, как вы отличаете:

- верные ответы от ошибочных,
- достоверные источники от недостоверных,
- научное знание от ненаучного?

С трудом представляю, как можно подтвердить или опровергнуть некоторое утверждение об истории языка или этимологии слова, но предполагаю, что должны быть соответствующие научные методы. В чём смысл ответов, содержащих голословные утверждения и не содержащих ссылок на подтверждающие их научные исследования?

Нередко вижу в ответах «эксперт такой-то говорит следующее...». Почему [отсылка к авторитету](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_verecundiam) является корректным способом доказательства? Авторитетность субъективна, для вас авторитетен доктор филологических наук, а для кого-то [доктор математических наук](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), увлекающийся [любительской лингвистикой (т.н. «лингвофричеством»)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

По моим субъективным ощущениям, на данном сайте (и в целом на всех подобных сайтах) довольно много ничем не подтверждённых и зачастую ошибочных ответов. В качестве иллюстрации приведу различные утверждения о происхождении матерных слов, которые я обнаружил, расставляя метку [обсценная-лексика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Начнём с хорошего. Вопрос «[Происхождение мата](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/31733/177015)». Автор принятого ответа придерживается такой версии:

> Слова эти сами по себе табуированными не были, просто постепенно они стали употребляться исключительно в "ночи любви"

Эта версия хотя бы не противоречит здравому смыслу. Автор сам делает оговорку:

> в интернете полно исследований и псевдоиссдедований на эту тему, тут даже и не знаешь, чему верить

Тот же вопрос, соседний ответ:

> Мат=материализация. Проговаривание нехваток на телесном уровне ("у кого что болит"). Мат существовал до зарождения культуры, после её возникновения был табуирован, но не смирился. С тех пор ведёт с нею борьбу не на жизнь, а на смерть.

Что, простите, я только что прочитал? Это какая-то смесь любительской лингвистики, любительской психологии и любительской культурологии. Вот от того же автора [в ответе на другой вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/36162/177015):

> Мат неприличен. Этим прилагательным обозначается то, что не должно происходить при ликах (святых). Мат безобразен: должен звучать без образов (святых).

https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/711/177015. Из принятого ответа:

> Скорее всего, русский мат изначально являлся заклинаниями языческих богов...

Серьёзно, сами боги использовали русский мат? Можно увидеть доказательства?

Ещё один интересный [ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/428819/177015):

> На мой взгляд, главные матерные слова на буквы "Х" и "П" происходят с языков Мордвы, точнее с мокшанского и эрзянского, а именно от слов произносимых на разных диалектах, как ГУЙ -ЗМЕЙ или КУЙ -ЗМЕЙ и ПИЗА -Норка, Нора или Гнездо, Дупло!
>
> Да, невольно и связь есть определённая с тем же змеем-искусителем.
>
> Кстати, возможно случайно, но сперматозоиды тоже змеевидной формы

«Совпадение? Не думаю!».

Нашёл ещё один перл, не удержался от того чтобы и его процитировать:

> Корень яр, он же гер, он же хер означает нечто неудержимо поднимающееся: Ярило (весенне солнце), яро (весна), ярость. Однокоренными являются Германия и немецкое обращение Herr(господин).

Германия! Германия, [герр Карл](https://tjournal.ru/p/coral)!

Answer (score 4):

Критерии научного знания во всех науках одни и те же, никакой особой специфики в лингвистике и языкознании нет. Не буду на этом подробно останавливаться, как мне показалось - ваш вопрос не совсем об этом.

У вас не хватает базовых знаний по предмету, вам нужно рассказать о таких вещах, как лексикостатистика, список Сводеша, глоттохронология, фонетические законы, модели пересчёта и многие, многие другие.

Я могу порекомендовать следующие простые материалы для начального погружения в тему, это мой любимый цикл "Открытые лекции полит.ру":

- [История языков](http://polit.ru/article/2005/11/09/mudrak/)
- [Язык во времени](http://polit.ru/article/2009/04/30/mudrak/)
- [Что такое «ностратическая гипотеза» и почему многие её боятся](http://polit.ru/article/2013/03/05/ps_sc20_starostin2/)

Если хотите несколько формальных критериев, то вот вам цитата из википедии:

> Академик А. А. Зализняк в своей статье «О профессиональной и
>   любительской лингвистике» указывает, что «сочинение о языке
>   любительское, если в нём встречается хотя бы одно из следующих
>   утверждений»:
>
> - Звук А может переходить в звук В — без уточнения языка и периода времени.
> - Гласные не имеют значения, существен только «костяк согласных».
> - Слово А получилось в результате обратного прочтения слова В.
> - Такая-то древняя надпись из той или иной страны читается по-русски.
> - Название А такого-то города или такой-то реки той или иной дальней страны — это просто искаженное русское слово В (из чего видно,
>     что эта страна была некогда населена русскими или они овладели ею).
> - Такие-то языки произошли из русского, причём современного, а не его древнего предшественника.

Это краткий ответ на часть вопроса "С трудом представляю, как можно".

Насчёт второй части вопроса, "В чём смысл ответов, содержащих голословные утверждения".

Ну как в чём? Самоутверждение, попытка выдать свои  доморощенные изыскания за науку, придать им вес, солидность. Фриков во все времена и в любой науке хватает.

К сожалению, у нас в стране даже на уровне министров проходят ненаучные работы ("Единственный критерий научности - работа должна быть на благо национальным интересам"), пышно цветёт такая псевдонаучная организация, как РАЕН, живут и здравствуют псведолингвист Задоронов и псевдоисторик Фоменко и так далее.

Если вы внимательно читали сайт, то таких фриков на сайте немного, репутации они много не набрали (в основном -- плюсование друг друга по кругу), а посты их вызывают лишь гомерический хохот даже у непрофессионалов -- и даже опытные участники устали комментировать, где в ответах ошибках, слишком много там ненаучного и псевдонаучного.

Comment: Вы привели признаки лингвофричества. Оно действительно и так неплохо распознаётся. Но как насчёт критериев достоверного научного знания? Вот некий участник с немаленькой репутацией пишет что-то о языке. В лучшем случае он упомянет фамилию автора, мнение которого транслирует. Ещё в трети случаев будет ссылка на другой сайт, где сидят и отвечают на вопросы такие же люди. В остальных случаях не будет ничего.

Comment: Я читал не больше сотни вопросов, но внимательно. За сегодняшний день отдал около 20 голосов против и поставил 14 тревог. Опять же, по моим субъективным ощущениям, безосновательных ответов очень много. (Разумеется, совсем уж махровыми фриками написана небольшая их часть).

Comment: Собственно, есть два пути: либо бы будете повышать свою квалификацию (и тогда начнёте узнавать общие места без ссылок на авторство и типовые логические связки), либо вы как непрофессионал можете ориентироваться на внешние признаки, только на днях обсуждали [вопрос репутации](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4379/). Сами же пишете: "участник с немаленькой репутацией".

Comment: Ну, все-таки не совсем корректно, что "никакой особой специфики в лингвистике и языкознании нет". Во-первых, почему языкознание и лингвистика разделены, не понятно. Во-вторых, в той же физике часто то или иное явление проверяемо (не всегда сразу, не всегда с первого раза), что нельзя (или можно, но с огромнейшей оговоркой и не во всех разделах) сделать в лингвистических исследованиях.

Comment: Компаративистика — это замечательно, однако тут речь о русском языке, и, если уж рекомендовать, то сначала что-нибудь из его истории. Например, послушать какие-нибудь лекции А. А. Зализняка на Ютубе, почитать его "Из заметок о любительской лингвистике", прочитать "Почему языки такие разные?" В. А. Плунгяна... @NickVolynkin

Comment: А Задорнов, мб, дурачится... я бы лучше Чудинова вписал вместо него, вот там уже тяжёлый случай на самом деле; ну или, если вы радеете за компаративистику, то Вашкевича какого-нибудь с его многочисленными подвальными псевдоэтимологическими симиями.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Как определяется научность в гуманитарных науках?

Так же как и во всех остальных, только со своей спецификой. Основные критерии:

- **Опровержимость**. Любой вывод должен иметь, критерии, в случае несоблюдения которых он будет неверен. Например, слово "бистро" могло бы появится от русского "быстро", если бы было зафиксировано в 10-х - 20-х гг. XIX в., но так как оно зафиксировано значительно позднее, то эта теория скорее всего неверна. Большинство "фриковых" теорий этому принципу не соответствуют, указывая лишь на случайное сходство слов.
- **Доказательность**. Утверждение должно быть логично обосновано.

**2.** Как отличить достоверные источники от недостоверных?
Научные работы со ссылочным аппаратом более достоверны, чем научно-популярные, а те достовернее, чем анонимные блоги. Словари и статьи крупных учёных, **специализирующиеся** в рассматриваемой области наиболее достоверны, но это не означает, что их мнение истина в последней инстанции, но оно по крайней мере заслуживает того, чтобы его выслушать, даже если ты с ним не согласен.

**3.** Как отличить верный ответ от неверного?
А вот тут сложно. Провести самостоятельное этимологическое исследование почти невозможно, так как оно требует хорошего знания древних языков и данных о первых фиксациях слова, поэтому приходится доверять словарям. С орфографией и орфоэпией похожая ситуация, можно не соглашаться со словарями, но последнее слово за ними. Пунктуация же - это интерпретация Розенталя и Лопатина с учётом специфики конкретного текста. Существуют ещё вопросы, где верного и неверного ответа не может быть в принципе, лишь более и менее достоверные теории.